# Owncloud - disable or move temporary files

Tags: sync, dropbox, owncloud

I have a task - copy `dropbox` data into `owncloud`.

Imagine one computer with `dropbox` and `owncloud` clients installed to sync the same folder. Everything works fine, except for owncloud logs - it writes them into the same synced folder. Some files:

- .owncloudsync.log
- .csync_journal.db
- .csync_journal.db-shm
- .csync_journal.db-wal

It's possible in to add files in `owncloud` to `ignored files`, but it's not possible in `dropbox` client. So, after any change in `dropbox`, it syncs with `owncloud`, changes it's logs, updates in `dropbox`. Then, for all `dropbox` users annoying notification appeared that log-file changed.

How to disable or move temporary files from sync folder?

Other way like is not available:

- Make `dropbox` client read-only;
- Copy from `dropbox` sync folder to `owncloud` dedicated sync folder by `cron`/OS `scheduler`.

Comment: So you're looking for a way to keep them in sync, rather than just transfer data once from one to the other?

Comment: To keep in sync.